# Saving information into file and load it on start?

Tags: android, load, save

Basicaly what im intrested in doing is when i give my app some GeoPoint i want to save i want it to save this to a file on the phone.. But i have no idea how i will do this saving, I need to save the longitude, latitude, and two strings for each object and when i make a save.. And this is for each point i want to save.. And this brings me how i will make the loading when the app starts.. Maybe i could make it save all information for each object on separate lines and it would be easier to load it?

I never had experience with saving and loading this is totaly new to me so how would i solve something like this?

Comment: If you only need to remember the last GeoPoint, look into savedPreferences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've asked a general question so the best I can do is give you a general answer. You'll want to do this reading and writing in your onCreate and onDestroy methods for your activities. For details on storing persistent data on the android phone, please read the android [Data Storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) article.